# recursion in my quicksort

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I'm currently trying to implement quicksort on an array in javascript. I have the overall layout but for some reason the recursion isn't working. It seems to have worked for the 2nd iteration of the code but after that, it seems to just mess up. Not sure what I did wrong.

```js
function main() {
  var type = "quicksort"
  var testArray = [9, 6, 5, 0, 8, 2, 4, 7];

  quickSort(testArray, 0, testArray.length - 1);
  for (var i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(testArray[i]);
  }

}

function quickSort(array, start, end) {
  var type = "quicksort"
  var pIndex;

  if (start <= end) {
    pIndex = partition(array, start, end);
    quickSort(array, start, pIndex - 1);
    quickSort(array, pIndex + 1, end);
  }


}

function partition(array, start, end) {
  var x = end;
  console.log(start);
  var i = start - 1;
  var temp;

  for (var j = 0; j < end - 1; j++) {
    if (array[j] <= x) {
      i++;
      temp = array[j];
      array[j] = array[i];
      array[i] = temp;
      temp = 0;


    }
  }

  temp = array[i + 1];
  array[i + 1] = array[x];
  array[x] = temp;
  temp = 0;

  return i + 1;
}

main();
```

Comment: What does "mess up" mean? What is it doing wrong?

Comment: At least one correction, `var x = array[end]`. Side note, using the name `end` is misleading, perhaps change it to `last`. The typical name usage for the last element of a sub-array is `array[end-1]` or `array[last]` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistakes are

@function quickSort

```
  //if (start <= end)  
  // should be 
  if (start < end)
```

@function partition

```
//for (var j = 0; j <= end - 1; j++) {
// if (array[j] <= x) {
// Should be
for (var j = start; j <= end - 1; j++) {
  if (array[j] <= array[x]) {
```

Following code should work.

```
function main() {
  var type = "quicksort"
  var testArray = [9, 6, 5, 0, 8, 2, 4, 7];

  quickSort(testArray, 0, testArray.length - 1);
  for (var i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(testArray[i]);
  }

}

function quickSort(array, start, end) {
  var type = "quicksort";
  var pIndex;

  if (start < end) {
    pIndex = partition(array, start, end);
    quickSort(array, start, pIndex - 1);
    quickSort(array, pIndex + 1, end);
  }


}

function partition(array, start, end) {
  var x = end;
  console.log(start);
  var i = start - 1;
  var temp;

  for (var j = start; j <= end - 1; j++) {
    if (array[j] <= array[x]) {
      i++;
      temp = array[j];
      array[j] = array[i];
      array[i] = temp;
      temp = 0;
    }
  }

  temp = array[i + 1];
  array[i + 1] = array[x];
  array[end] = temp;
  temp = 0;

  return i + 1;
}

main();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

Some mistakes:

`if (start <= end) {` there is no need to treat case `start = end`

How  `for (var j = 0` starts with 0 when range begins from start?

`if (array[j] <= x) {`  you compare index with item value?